# Deleting function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

```html
               <div class="panel-heading ">Liste des Garanties Marché 
                                            <button type="button" name="add" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="setFlagEdit(false, {})" data-target="#myModal"><img src="../images/add.png"></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body" >
                                            <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Type</th>
                                                        <th>Date Caution</th>
                                                        
                                                        <th>Montant (TND)</th>
                                                        <th>Montant Restitué</th>
                                                        <th>Date Restitution</th>
                                                        <th>Etat</th>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr ng-repeat="c in listeCaution">
                                                        <td>{{c.reference}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{c.dateCaution}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{c.mt}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{c.mr}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{c.daterp}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{c.etat}}</td>
                                                        <td><button type="submit" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  ng-click="setFlagEdit(true, f)" ><img src="../images/edit.png"/></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                         <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" type="button" class="btn" ng-click="ConfirmerDelete(c)" ><img src="../images/rubbish-bin-red.png"/></button>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                                <tfoot>
                                                </tfoot>
                                            </table>
                                            <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
                                             <li ng-class="{active:$index==pageCourante}" class="clickable" ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index">
                                              <a ng-click="gotoPage($index)">{{$index}}</a>
                                             </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
```

```html
var app = angular.module("marcheApp",[]);
app.controller("marcheAppController",function($scope,$http,$window,$location){
 
 
 $scope.marche={};
 $scope.saveMarche=addMarche;
 $scope.saveCaution=addCaution;
 $scope.flagEdit=false;
 $scope.setFlagEdit = function(flag,m){
  $scope.flagEdit=flag;
  $scope.Marche=m;
  $scope.listeCaution=$scope.marche.caution;
  console.log($scope.marche);
 }
 $scope.confirmerDelete= function(m){
  //   url /fournisseurs/f.idFournisseur
  // .post => .delete
 }
 function addMarche(){
  
  //$scope.projet={'matrAdj':$scope.matrAdj,'nomAdj':$scope.nomAdj,'type':$scope.type,'taux':$scope.taux,'pays':$scope.pays,'email':$scope.email,'tel':$scope.tel,'fax':$scope.fax,'adresse':$scope.adresse};
//  $http.post("http://localhost:8080/addFournisseur", $scope.fournisseur)
//  .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
//   //$scope.projet=data;
//   //$scope.chargerProjets();
//  });
  $scope.marche.caution=$scope.listeCaution;
  console.log($scope.marche);
  $http.post('http://localhost:8080/marches',$scope.marche)
  .then(function(response){
//       $scope.marche=response.data;//(scope.produit=data)on va affiché le prod ajouté avec son id où? allez au html NewProduit.html
//       $scope.mode=1;//une fois que j'ai les données
    console.log(response.data);
//    $scope.chargerFournisseurs();
//    location.reload();
  },function(response){
       console.log(response.data);
  });
 }
 

 $scope.pageMarches=[];
 $scope.listeMarches=[];
 $scope.pageCourante=0;
 $scope.pages=[];
 $scope.pageCourante=0;
 $scope.size=5;
 var idc=0;
 var recherche=false;
 $scope.listeCaution=[];
 $scope.chargerMarches=function()
 {
  $http.get('http://localhost:8080/marches?page='+$scope.pageCourante+'&size='+$scope.size,$scope.marche)
  .then(function(response){
   $scope.listeMarches=response.data;
    console.log(response.data);
    $scope.pages=new Array(response.data.totalPages);
//    $('#closeModalAjout').click();
//    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
    recherche=false;
  },function(response){
       console.log(response.data);
  });
  
 }
 
 
 $scope.chargerMarches();
 $scope.gotoPage=function(p){
  $scope.pageCourante=p;
  if (recherche){
   $scope.chercherMarches();
  } else {
   $scope.chargerMarches();
  }
  
 }
 
 
 
 $scope.idMarche;
 

 $scope.chercherMarches=function(){
  $http.get("http://localhost:8080/chercherMarches?idMarche="
    +$scope.idMarche+"&page="+$scope.pageCourante+"&size="+$scope.size)
  .then(function(response){
       $scope.listeMarches=response.data;
       $scope.pages=new Array(response.data.totalPages);
    recherche=true;
  },function(response){
       console.log(response.data);
  })
 }
```

Can someone help me in completing the function of deletiong a fournisseur f ?

in htat way : means with the if and http://localhost:8080/.. and .delete
ConfirmerDelete in the img bellow .. Thank You much

Comment: It is unclear exactly what your asking, can you explain a little more?

Comment: Include code, as actual `code` - not an image. If possible, please. (makes it easier for us to run)

Comment: i added the img in which the function is not completed .. help me in completing it plz and thank u much

Comment: ^^ code? would be much better than an image

Comment: i added the code .. the function ConfirmerDelete is missing . u can plz help me in completing it ?

Comment: it's easy just  call the post method with the propitiate parameters and the get the index of the object in the array and splice it. angular will update the view itself